# PyArrow: read single file from partitioned parquet dataset is unexpectedly slow

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, pyarrow

I am having some problems with the speed of loading `.parquet` files. However, I don't know what I am doing wrong.

**Problem**

I am trying to read a single `.parquet` file from from my local filesystem which is the partitioned output from a spark job. Such that there are `.parquet` files in hierarchical directories named `a=x` and `b=y`.

To achieve this, I am using `pandas.read_parquet` (which uses `pyarrow.parquet.read_table`) for which I include the `filters` kwarg. The run time of using the `filters` is way longer than I would expect.

```py
# The following runs for about 55 seconds
pd.read_parquet(<path_to_entire_dataset>, filters=[[('a', '=', 'x'), ('b', '=', 'y')]])

# The following runs for about 0.04 seconds
pd.read_parquet(<path_to_entire_dataset>/a=x/b=y/)

# The following runs for about 70 seconds
pd.read_parquet(<path_to_entire_dataset>)
```

Reading a single parquet file by specifying filters is only slightly faster than loading the entire dataset, where I would expect a run time approximately linear in the amount of files.

**What mistake do I make here?**

I realize that simply putting the filters in the path would work, however this will quickly become complex as what I want to filter on will / can change. Besides, I think `read_table` should be able to load this data efficiently.

PS: The entire dataset contains many millions of rows, the data I want to load is only a few thousand rows.

### Edit 1:

As suggested by 0x26res I manually defined the partitioning, this lead to a significant speed up, but still not as much as I would have expected. In this situation the run time was about 5 seconds.

```
partitioning = HivePartitioning(
    pa.schema([
        pa.field('a', pa.string()),
        pa.field('b', pa.int32()),
    ])
)

pd.read_parquet(
    <path_to_entire_dataset>,
    engine='pyarrow',
    filters=[
        [
            ('a', '=', x),
            ('b', '=', y),
        ]
    ],
    partitioning=partitioning
)
```

Comment: I made an earlier comment but I think I read your question wrong.  Is your dataset partitioned by spark so the directory names are formatted like `a=x` and `b=y`?

Comment: Yes, just in case it was not clear I updated the description.

Comment: Can you help me to understand the performance a bit more?  How many files matched that filter?  How large were these files?  How large was the uncompressed table read by those files?

Comment: There is exactly one file that matches that filter. There are about 100_000 files, each up to 100Kb. Uncompressed the table was around the 10Gb. Like I said in my question, I could of course specify the files I want in the path and potentially load the several files I need and combine them using `pd.concat`. However, I want to understand why this is not as fast as I expect it to be. I thought that was one of the major benefits of  parquet, you load the data you need, not more.

Comment: is there any update or solution on this issue you can share? Would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Given the run time, I suspect arrow is opening every files and then filtering.

Maybe you can try specifiying the partitioning so arrow can be smarter about it:

```
import pyarrow as pa

partitioning = pa.dataset.HivePartitioning(
        pa.schema([
            pa.field('a', pa.string()),
            pa.field('b', pa.string())
        ])
    )

pd.read_parquet(<path_to_entire_dataset>, filters=[[('a', '=', 'x'), ('b', '=', 'y')]], partitioning=partitioning)
```

Comment: I was not aware that I would need to define the partitioning like this. When I did it resulted in a big speed up, the reading of the file only takes 5 seconds now. It is still not as fast as I would expect it to be. I will be updating my question, however will not verify your answer yet.

Comment: It should get discovered automatically.  `pd.read_parquet` calls `pyarrow.parquet.read_table` and the default partitioning behavior should be to discover hive-style partitions (i.e. the ones you have).  The fact that you have to specify this means that discovery is failing.  If you could create a reproducible example and submit it to [Arrow JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/ARROW/issues) it would be helpful.