# R arrow query extremely slow first time, fast thereafter?

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, dplyr, apache-arrow, dbplyr

I'm going through [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O42LUmJZPx0) tutorial of how to use arrow instead of regular dplyr. Second and subsequent times I run queries on this dataset it's very fast, but the first one is incredibly slow (times below).

#### Minimal Reproducible Example

Here's an MRE of what I'm doing. This first bit is to obtain the ~70gb parquet dataset (takes ~6 hours, depending on internet connection).

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(arrow)

# copy_files(
#   from = s3_bucket("ursa-labs-taxi-data-v2"),
#   to = "~/Datasets/nyc-taxi"
# )
```

then, in preparation:

```r
nyc_taxi <- open_dataset("~/Datasets/nyc-taxi")

# small file to join to later
nyc_taxi_zones <- read.csv(url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/djnavarro/arrow-user2022/main/data/taxi_zone_lookup.csv")) %>% 
  janitor::clean_names()

airport_zones <- nyc_taxi_zones %>% 
  filter(str_detect(zone, "Airport")) %>% 
  pull(location_id)
# [1]   1 132 138


# Alter schema (otherwise joining int32 and int64 cols won't work) 
nyc_taxi_zones2 <- nyc_taxi_zones %>% 
  transmute(
    dropoff_location_id = location_id,
    dropoff_borough = borough,
    dropoff_zone = zone
  ) %>% 
  as_arrow_table(
    schema = schema(
      dropoff_location_id = int64(),
      dropoff_borough = utf8(),
      dropoff_zone = utf8()  
    )
  )
```

and finally, the actual operation:

```r
start_time <- Sys.time()
nyc_taxi %>% 
  filter(
    pickup_location_id %in% airport_zones
  ) %>% 
  select(
    matches("datetime"),
    matches("location_id")
  ) %>% 
  left_join(
    nyc_taxi_zones2
  ) %>% 
  count(dropoff_zone) %>% 
  arrange(desc(n)) %>% 
  collect()

end_time <- Sys.time()
end_time - start_time
```

- First time running this on a fresh ec2: 17.7 minutes!
- Second time running it in the same R session, 11 seconds!
- Note that after closing and reopening RStudio, it's still 11 seconds.

#### What I've tried so far

- Thinking the bottleneck might be an I/O constraint, I switched to an IO optimized ec2, upgraded SSD and a few other things. They didn't make any substantial difference.
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66340044/5783745) possibly related question/answer looks like some promising leads (it's in python, but perhaps the root cause (not specifying partitioning) seems like a possible explanation for this problem.

Comment: This is an interesting question but I'd suggest a couple of things. The data clearly needs to be reasonably large to replicate this issue but does it need to be 70gb? If it was 2gb I might have a go at running this. Secondly, your actual operation is a pipe which does several things. Do you only see the timing discrepancy with all these steps in this order? If so it would be good to add that to the question. If not, it would be good to know if you see it with just `filter()`, `select()`, `left_join()` or `arrange()`?.

Comment: @SamR the operation above is an example, but up to and including the `left_join()`, skipping the count and arrange, but then calling `collect()`, it will still have the same problem (first time running takes ~20min, subsequent runs ~12 seconds).

Comment: Does this only occur on ec2? I'm wondering whether it's something to do with how data is stored/cached between ec2 and s3 or if the aws aspect is irrelevant. But I'm afraid I'm not wondering enough to download 70gb of data...

Comment: @SamR I don't blame you on the download front (I'll see if I can share a public amazon machine image so you could start an ec2 from an image with the data already available if sufficiently keen - I'll suss it out and report back shortly). I have suspected similar, but I can't explain why the ec2 would have any issue. I'll add the ec2 tag to the question just in case.

Comment: (1) Does this have anything to do with EC2? You download the file from EC2, and _then_ start your profiling. (2) If I had to guess (and I will also not be testing with a 70GB download), `arrow` is doing some additional indexing on the first read and, since you're using the same arrow connection, reusing it on the second query.

Comment: @r2evans sounds plausible. When I close and reopen RStudio (i.e. end and start a new R session), the queries are fast (no slow query to begin with), and I can't spot anywhere (on windows) that any new files were created (I poked around looking for non-hidden and hidden files in and around the dataset directory, looking for any index/schema file(s) arrow might have created)

Comment: @r2evans regarding the download of the files from S3, I had to do that once, but I created an image so never had to do it a second time. When I figure out how to get my github credentials off that image I'll update it and make it public so anyone can start an ec2 with the 70gb data immediately available.

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but I (for one) am not spinning up an ec2 image (even if I had credits lined up on aws, which I don't :-). Still thinking, though ... what is your OS? Windows, for one, marks a file as untrusted (I forget the term) when it is downloaded from the internet. For some files, this "mark" changes the app; for example, Excel will not enable macros on an xlsm downloaded from an untrusted source. Is it possible that what's happening is the OS is scanning/verifying the file on the first `arrow::` connection?

Comment: @r2evans The OS is 'Microsoft Windows Server 2022' (ami-0fa4dfd1533851540). I should try on linux or some other OS to see if it's something specific to the OS/version I'm using. That will take me a while as I'll have to download the dataset on the new OS. But if it solves that would be a nice breakthrough.

Comment: Try this: copy from the ec2 instance fresh, then do something else to the file other than `arrow::`. For instance, try `time md5sum nyc_taxi/*`. Then repeat that, and see if the times are different. If they are different then this is a question for Windows gurus, not R. If it is the same and you still see the difference in R, then ... perhaps `md5sum` did not trigger the OS thingy, so that doesn't mean a whole lot ... in which case, perhaps download, then `ignore <- lapply(list.files("nyc-taxi", full.names=TRUE), readBin, what="raw", n=10)` and then do your timing.

Comment: Frankly, I thought it would be the overhead of unifying schemas and/or unraveling the partitioning, but since you say you restarted R and saw "fast" on the first query, that seems to dispell that rumor. However ... confirm, is your connection saved in an `.RData` project file, or when you restart R are you creating a new `arrow::open_dataset(.)` object and it is fast on the first try?

Comment: Any progress @stevec?